# SpringBoot FeignClient Method has too many paramters

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

im using spring-cloud's feignClient and things go wrong when there is more than one Beans paramters in my interface,error shows like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract com.wxl.pros.test.web.common.CommonResObject com.wxl.pros.test.web.feign.OrderFeignClient.createOrder(com.wxl.pros.test.services.form.order.CreateOrderForm,com.wxl.pros.test.services.vo.User)
    at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:128)
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:114)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:133)
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(Contract.java:64)
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixDelegatingContract.parseAndValidatateMetadata(HystrixDelegatingContract.java:34)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:146)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:53)
    at feign.Feign$Builder.target(Feign.java:209)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.HystrixTargeter.target(HystrixTargeter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Here is one of my interface methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/order/createOrder",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public CommonResObject createOrder(@RequestBody OrderForm orderForm,@RequestBody User user);
```

Comment: a request has only a single body.. How should that map to 2 different parameters...

Comment: my bad ,i find it too,thanx for that,and now i meet the needs where two objects is reqired when calling this method, how can i achive this by receiving two or more object params?

Comment: Wrap them in another object...

Answer (score 12):

If you have multiple arguments with one request body and more params. Specify the argument types using exact annotations:

```
ResponseMessage<String> getCustomInformation((@RequestBody CustomRequest request, @RequestParam("language") String language,
            @RequestParam("channel") String channel, @RequestParam("requestId") String requestId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them together in a third pojo:

```
public class Order {
     OrderForm orderForm;
     User user;
     public Order(@JsonProperty("orderForm") orderForm, @JsonProperty("user") User user) {
         this.orderForm = orderForm;
         this.user = user;
     }
}
```

Then your API becomes sth like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/order/createOrder",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public CommonResObject createOrder(@RequestBody Order order);
```

Answer (score 0):

@RequestBody can only exist one. If you have multiple objects that need to be transferred, you can use json to merge multiple objects.